# Windows Services & WCF

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I need to create a Windows Service to watch a folder on our network and action files that are placed within it. The process is quite slow and I need the ability to check the progress from a client application (which will be running in about 10 places on the same network as the machine running the Windows service).

Is hosting some WCF service in the windows service the right way to go about this and if so, are there any resources on how I would do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems a reasonable approach to me.

you can get details of how to host a WCF service inside a windows service in the [MSDN how to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_windows_hosting.aspx) code project page also has an example.

you might need to debug start up issues with the service, and I find adding a

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

to the beginning of the `OnStart` method is the easiest way of doing that.  it enables you to debug through the start up process of your service and see any exceptions that occur.